# php regular expression to get the specific url

Tags: php, regex, url

I would like to get the urls from a webpage that starts with "../category/" from these tags below:

```
<a href="../category/product/pc.html" target="_blank">PC</a><br>
<a href="../category/product/carpet.html" target="_blank">Carpet</a><br>
```

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No regular expressions is required. A simple XPath query with DOM will suffice:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "../category/")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue.' = '.$node->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will print:

```
PC = ../category/product/pc.html
Carpet = ../category/product/carpet.html
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but I haven't used this before and I would like to get the contents from the link. Something like "http://www.example.com/p/carpet.html". How will I add this to the code?

Comment: @user704278: If you want to rewrite the URL, just do: `$new_href = 'example.com/p/'.basename($node->getAttribute('href'));`

Answer (score 0):

This regex searches for your `../category/` string:

```
preg_match_all('#......="(\.\./category/.*?)"#', $test, $matches);
```

All text literals are used for matching. You can replace the ..... to make it more specific. Only the `\.` need escaping. The `.*?` looks for a variable length string. And `()` captures the matched path name, so it appears in $matches. The manual explains the rest of the syntax. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php