# php regular expression to get the specific url

Tags: php, regex, url

I would like to get the urls from a webpage that starts with `"http://example.com/category/"` from these tags below:

`<td><a href="http://example.com/category/subcategory/product/257849"  title="Sample Title">Test</a></td>`

Note:

257849 = random number

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Another question of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636972/php-regular-expression-to-get-the-specific-url

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the fixed base URL asis in the regex, and use `[\w/]+` to match any combination of letters, numbers and the / slash afterwards:

```
preg_match('#http://example.com/category/[\w/]+#', $text, $match);
print $match[0];
```

And to extract all urls at once, use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead.

Comment: It's unlikely but there are other characters like % that could be valid and appear in the URL

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#http://example.com/category[^"]+#', $text, $a);
```

The result will be in $a